# Is there such a column type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For any two values `a` and `b` of such type,(`a<b`)there always exists a `c` satisfying:

```
a<c<b
```

Answer (score 2):

decimal ( float ) type

Comment: What if it's 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000001 and 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000002?

Comment: Ok. if you pass that level of complexity I recommend you to read about trees in the databases. here is a link http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures?src=embed

Answer (score 1):

No.  Mathematically for the property to hold true, the numbers must be from an infinite domain.  Decimals and floats may have a large domain but it is not infinite.

There is a simple proof by counter example, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: ENUM type with just just one element. name ENUM('one').  Since there is no a and b such that a < b the property is vacuously true.